# Mysql Query Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

My query shows Invalid use of group function when i want to get Average

```
SELECT u.id, 
       TRUNCATE(AVG(SUM(m.carbs) / 
                    ( SUM(m.carbs) + SUM(m.fat) + SUM(m.protein) )), 2), 
       DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create)) AS Cdate, 
       goal.what, 
       goal.value 
FROM   `meal` AS m, 
       `user_history` AS u 
       LEFT JOIN goal 
              ON goal.what = 'Carbs' 
                 AND goal.user_id = 50 
WHERE  u.meal_id = m.id 
       AND u.user_id = 50 
GROUP  BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create))
```

sample data

meal table

```
Id carbs fat protein

4   10   30     18   
6   17   4       2
```

user history table

```
Id mealid  date

1   4       20014-07-21
2   6       20014-07-21
```

need cumulative average of every day meal taken for carbs

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to scroll that far to the right...try reformatting.

Comment: Why do you do half old-style joins and half new-style joins? To me, that makes it harder to follow.

Comment: You can't do `avg(sum())`.  I don't know what you intend, so I have no idea how to fix this.  Sample data and desired results are always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when grouping in SQL you will need to group by all fields that are not aggregate functions (by aggregate I mean SUM, COUNT, AVG etc.).
Try adding u.id, goal.what and goal.value to the GROUP BY statement.
Read the first paragraph on [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) for more information.

Comment: mysql has no such limits. you can select any field you want, whether grouped or aggregated or not.

Comment: You sure can... you just won't get sensible results.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is supposed to agglomerate your rows on a defined existing field, whereas you try to group on a non-existent / calculated field `DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create))`

Try this:

```
GROUP  BY Cdate
```

since Cdate is defined as the calculated field in your selected fields

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to you need

```
GROUP By DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(u.create)), u.id, goal.what, goal.value
```